# Encrypt a hex string in java

Tags: java, encryption, hex

I would like to ask for any suggestions about my problem. I need to encrypt a hexadecimal string. I must not to use the built-in functions of java because it doesn't work in my server. In short, I have to hard code an algorithm or any means of encrypting the message. Anyone who could help me with this? thanks a lot!

here is the code.

```
public Encrypt(SecretKey key, String algorithm) {

 try {
     ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
     dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
     ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
     dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
 } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
     System.out.println("EXCEPTION: NoSuchPaddingException");
 } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
     System.out.println("EXCEPTION: NoSuchAlgorithmException");
 } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
     System.out.println("EXCEPTION: InvalidKeyException");
 }
}

public void useSecretKey(String secretString) {


 try {
     SecretKey desKey       = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();
     SecretKey blowfishKey  = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Blowfish").generateKey();
     SecretKey desedeKey    = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESede").generateKey();

     Encrypt desEncrypter = new Encrypt(desKey, desKey.getAlgorithm());
     Encrypt blowfishEncrypter = new Encrypt(blowfishKey, blowfishKey.getAlgorithm());
     Encrypt desedeEncrypter = new Encrypt(desedeKey, desedeKey.getAlgorithm());

     desEncrypted       = desEncrypter.encrypt(secretString);
     blowfishEncrypted  = blowfishEncrypter.encrypt(secretString);
     desedeEncrypted    = desedeEncrypter.encrypt(secretString);
 } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {}
}
```

those are the methods i used. no problem if it is run as an application but then when i put it to my server which is the glassfish server an exception occured and it says no such algorithm.

Comment: You should never write your own encryption algorithm.  ...What do you mean, the built-in functions don't work on your server?

Comment: "because it doesnt work on my server"! - doesn't sound like a reason to discard industry-grade algorithms created after of years of research by teams of scientists dedicating a better part of their lives to the field of encryption.

Comment: clarity and details are the key to a satisfactory answer

Comment: @BlueRaja: Seconded.  The java security functions MUST work or your Java install is broken -- standard encryption functions are intrinsic parts of the core libraries.  You may just be using them incorrectly -- the bit that fetches an implementation can be kind of nonintuitive.  Can you post your non-working code using them?

Comment: i never meant not to use the algorithms that teams of scientists did. What i was trying to tell is that i would like to ask some help about the codings of a well-known public key encryption so i can use it in my program...

Comment: @twintwins: have you tried something like this? http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html

Comment: @blueraja: i have added my codes above. it works fine but then when i put it in my server, it doesn't work. i do not know how will i solve this. my friend said it is just the path of my jdk but i dont know how to connect my jdk path to my glassfish server.

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't very helpful - please give details of what happens when you try using it on your server.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: ok. thanks for correcting me about it. upon triggering the class for encrypting the string, an exception popped out since i used joptionpane for it. the exception says, "java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: DES KeyGenerator not available". this is the exception. but when i run it as a simple app, the class goes through it..the string can be encrypted. why is this so?

Comment: @twintwins - without a doubt, you are solving your problem the hard way.  The easy way is to figure out the configuration issue that is stopping the crypto running on Glassfish.  It is probably something really simple to fix ... and if you give us more details we can probably help.

Comment: yup. i knew it that i'm doing this the hard way. i want to use the cryptography library of java but then i cant figure out how to set the path for the library.

I'm using eclipse version: 3.4.2 and os fedora.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about changing the code - sort out the environment.

You say it works when you run it as a command-line app - I assume you mean on your desktop. Can you do the same on the server?

What version of Java are you using in each place? Make sure that you check which version is being used in Glassfish - it may not be the same one you get when you run `java -version` on the command line.

As an aside, I hope your *real* code doesn't swallow exceptions like this.

Comment: hi. here is my java version. my os is fedora. java version "1.6.0_13"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_13-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 11.3-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: @twinstwins: I strongly suspect (or at least *hope*) that's not the version running on the web server (given that it's using the client VM). *What is your server running?*

Answer (score 0):

Try RC4 algorithm, it's easy to implement.

Comment: I've heard that ROT13 is easy to implement too :-)

Comment: hi! i tried this algorithm upon giving me this i appreciate it. I tried it but then i noticed that the encrypted string has undesirable characters in it. how can i make it a string with no undesirable characters? thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, obviously ... if you feed a HEX string into an encryption algorithm, the output is unlikely to be a HEX string.  If that is a problem, you should probably encrypt your data BEFORE you convert to HEX.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely due to some kind of stuff-up with the Java bootclasspath that is in force when Glassfish is started.  This often bites when an app server is launched from an IDE.  For example:

```
> On 30-5-2005 8:00, Uwe Peuker wrote:
>
> It's probably caused by the way how/when Eclipse passes
> the -Xbootclasspath parameter to the java executable that's being
> launched.
>
> Don't know for 3.1RC1, but for older releases it depends on the setting
> "Use system default libraries" in the JRE configuration (Window ->
> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> (select JRE) -> Edit)
>
> When "Use system default libraries" is unchecked (off), Eclipse adds
> the -Xbootclasspath parameter --with all the libs in the list-- to the
> java executable. If the list doesn't include the crypto libraries, it
> results in the NoSuchAlgorithmException.
> Otherwise, when "Use system default libraries" is checked, Eclipse doesn't
> add -Xbootclasspath, so it allows the java executable to discover its own
> boot classpath including the crypto libraries.
> --
> Regards,
>
> Roland de Ruiter
> ___ ___
> /__/ w_/ /__/
> / \ /_/ / \
```

**EDIT** : in response to the OP's comment:

(In case it is is not obvious, I am neither Roland de Ruiter or Uwe Peuker.  I just found that email in a Google search, and posted it here for your information.)

Anyway, since the problem arises when you launch Glassfish from Eclipse, the first thing you should try is launching Glassfish (with your app) from the command line.  If that works (as I expect it will), then the problem is clearly with Eclipse and/or the way you are using it.

Assuming that I'm right, the next thing will be to capture and examine the complete set of command line arguments that Eclipse is using when launching the JRE to run Glassfish.  In particular, you need to see if Eclipse is supplying a --bootclasspath option, and what its value is.

Comment: hi ronald! my version of eclipse is Eclipse Platform version: 3.4.2

i went to the JRE configuration you said but then i didn't seem to see teh "use system default libraries" and the checkbox for it. It is also my assumption that it is just the path of the libraries that hinders me in using the javax.crypto.

Answer (score 0):

Doing your own implementation of some cryptographic algorithms has great pedagogical value, but it is not easy to do it right. For symmetric encryption, the usual recommendation is AES, which is described in great (and quite clear) details in [FIPS-197](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf). AES is a block cipher, i.e. it encrypts blocks of 16 bytes. To encrypt a "message" (supposedly longer than 16 bytes), you need some chaining and padding (the set of conventions which convert the message into some 16-byte blocks for processing by the AES); this is not very easy either. See [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation) for an introduction on padding and chaining.

However, being unable to access the standard Java cryptographic implementations is suspicious. You shuold try to diagnose that first. Try listing (with some Java code) the registered providers, with code like this:

```
for (Provider p : Security.getProviders()) {
    System.out.printf("%s -> %s\n", p.getName(), p.getInfo());
}
```

then compare the output with what [the documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html) specifies. In particular the [list of Sun providers](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html).

(Note: we are talking about the server VM -- where your code runs -- and it may be a VM from some other vendor, e.g. IBM; the list of standard providers may vary.)